# X forwarding over ssh, issues with virtualbox

Tags: linux, ssh, x11, virtualbox

When trying to open virtualbox GUI over a forwarded session, I get the following error:

```
steve@remoteHost:~$ virtualbox
OpenGL Warning: Failed to connect to host. Make sure 3D acceleration is enabled for this VM.
```

Whilst `xeyes` works as expected.

How to debug this?

Anyone had similar issues?

Tried some env vars: `LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT` without success.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to have been remenants over a previous **Virtualbox** install.

Removing the packages, in my case:

```
$ sudo apt remove virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11
$ dpkg -l |grep virtualbox
ii  virtualbox-5.2                       5.2.22-126460~Ubuntu~xenial                  amd64        Oracle VM VirtualBox
rc  virtualbox-guest-utils               5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1                 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - non-X11 guest utilities
rc  virtualbox-guest-x11                 5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1                 amd64        x86 virtualization solution - X11 guest utilities
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account the error message you have "Make sure 3D acceleration is enabled for this VM", you have to:

1) Shut down your VM

2) Go on "Settings" section

3) Choose "Display" section then "Video"

4) Tick the box "Enable 3D acceleration" and Ok.

Let me know if it works :) ! Good Luck!